# Consultar total de registros em Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Em determinada parte da minha aplicação escrita em Laravel tenho essa consulta:

```
$counts = User::select(\DB::raw('count(*) as status_count, status'))
                    ->groupBy('status')
                    ->get();
```

Ela me retorna no mínimo 1 registro e no máximo 3, estes são justamente os status existente. Como faço para retornar uma linha extra contendo o total de registros?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Faça outro select. É a solução mais simples nesse caso.

```
$counts = User::select(\DB::raw('count(*) as status_count, status'))
                    ->groupBy('status')
                    ->get();

$total_counts = User::count();
```

Para evitar uma segunda query, então é possível utilizar o método `sum` do `Eloquent\Collection`.

```
 var_dump($counts->sum('status_count'));
```

Comment: Obrigado amigo, porém, estava tentando evitar uma consulta extra. Para tanto utilizei a sugestão do Rafael

Comment: Editei a resposta. Na verdade a solução dele é boa, mas você estaria refazendo algo que o Laravel já fez internamente. O método `Collection::sum` já faz um `Collection::reduce` internamente.

Comment: Legal. Muito obrigado

Answer (score 4):

Se optar por não fazer outro select, você pode utilizar o método reduce da collection, por exemplo:

```
$total = $counts->reduce(
    function ($carrier, $item) {
        return $carrier + $item->status_count;
    }, 0
);
```

Qualquer dúvida de uma olhada na [documentação](https://laravel.com/docs/master/collections#method-reduce).

Comment: Show de bola, meu objetivo era justamente não realizar uma consulta extra.

Comment: Se esse é o caso, então não precisava do `reduce`, eu sei um jeito mais simples :D